# What does this operation mean, and what is the function?

Tags: uml, modelio

I’m having a hard time figuring out what this means.

Can someone explain the operation for me? Specially the m and n values.

I know what system and int is. The screenshot is taking from a premade tutorial, so I’m sure it’s something the owner/author have made. I still just can’t figuring out what it should stand. I can’t see it been created anywhere.

[image: Operation]

Comment: See also http://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html

Answer (score 2):

The operation is shown with parameters in C-style, namely a comma-separated list of `name:type`. A `type` can be a primitive like `int`, `bool`, etc. But it can as well be a class or any other complex type. In your case you should look in your model whether you have classes called `nat` or `nat1`. If so, you should consult the editor of the model and tell that there's a convention to start types with a capital letter (so it should be `Nat` or `Nat1`).

Answer (score 0):

nat and nat1 must be a Class, Interface, DataType, Enumeration, etc. created in the model...

Comment: I think I'm too much a noob to understand that. Can we start from the very beginning.